# iPhone: How to populate a table view from XML data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, uitableview

Let's say I have XML data that I just downloaded from a web app api.

- How do I parse the data?
- How do I populate each cell of a table view with this data?

Comment: This is a pretty big question. Have you searched Google on "parsing xml iphone" etc.? Because there are lots of pre-typed-out answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial that does exactly what you are asking for.  It downloads an RSS feed (which is XML), parses it, then loads the data into a table.

It should be easy to modify this for your application.

http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

try using NSXMLParser. You can get the documentation[here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)